# Could we use two menus of wordpress in one site?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, media-queries

I am working on a wordpress project and I got a situation here,

I made two menus Menu1 and Menu2 in wordpress menu. Is it possible that Menu1 should be visible on just desktop and Menu2 should be visible on just small devices(tablets/mobiles) using media queries or anything else.

Because I want that when someone is visiting the site on desktop or laptop he should see the Menu1 but if the visitor visit the website on small devices he see the Menu2.

Is there any possible solution?

Comment: Refer below article - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156231/how-to-stop-mobile-theme-inheriting-desktop-navigation-menu/156494#156494

Answer (score 1):

Link recommended by @sangita is a good solution.

You can acheive this using css as well.

Add the following css:

```
.Menu1 {
  display: block;
}

.Menu2 {
display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .Menu1 {
    display: none;
  }
  .Menu2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Please do mind that this is not an optmium solution, page speed wise.